# Operator does not exist: text = bigint

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jboss, glassfish

I am trying to get our application that is currently running on glassfish 2.1 to work on jboss 6.1. And have the following problem, I don't think its related to the application server but rather something to do with postgres and /or hibernate.

Using the following software Postgresql 9.0, hibernate 3.6.6 on jboss and 3.2 on glassfish

Anyway, the problem.

this named query:

```
    @NamedQuery(name="entry.updateDuplicate",
    query="UPDATE entry SET timestamp = :timestamp WHERE username = :username AND searchDocument = :searchDocument")
```

this code:

```
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Entry.updateDuplicate");
    query.setParameter("timestamp", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.setParameter("sDocument", sString);

    int affected = query.executeUpdate();
```

generates this fault in the log:

```
    10:28:16,149 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: update fu set c_timestamp=? where c_username=? and c_document=?
    10:28:16,165 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
    10:28:16,165 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: operator does not exist: text = bigint
    Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
    Position: 77
```

the table is this:

```
    TABLE fu
    (
    id bigint NOT NULL, document text, timestamp timestamp without time zone, username character varying(255), CONSTRAINT fu_pkey PRIMARY KEY (c_id)
    )
```

Anyone have any idea, to me it seams like it has something to do with 'id' (the only bigInt field) but I can't figure out why or how to begin to solve it.

Any suggestion is most welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table definition that you posted contains `document text`, so is searchDocument by any chance a String annotated with `@Lob`? In that case this might be an issue with the Hibernate version that you're using on JBoss:

http://www.shredzone.de/cilla/page/299/string-lobs-on-postgresql-with-hibernate-36.html

Comment: Summary: Add `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")` under `@Lob`

Answer (score 2):

The driver can't convert a java `long` to SQL `text` (postgres is strict like that).

What is the type of variable `sString`? I suspect it's a `long`, not a `String`, but it needs to be a `String`.

As an aside, `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())` is equivalent to just `new Date()`

Comment: sString is an xml-document converted to a string. So the actual parameters that is used are an string, a string and a date.  And as i said in another comment, it works on glasfish so i doubt it is an syntactical error. The only bigInt in that tabel are the id, and that is not touched in this query

Comment: It sounds like a "bigint" in *java* - ie a `long` - that postgres is trying to convert to a text. Also, could it be that the `@Id` field of your entity class is defined as a `String`?

Comment: "postgres is stupid like that" - I'd replace that with "Postgres is wise enough to not do that"

Comment: @oliv fair enough. Changed "stupid" to "strict".

Answer (score 0):

The names query parameter is `searchDocument` but you set the parameter `sDocument`. And the actual paramater *variable* is named `sString` which suggests, that it is not a numeric type. Try something like `long` or `Long` (or `int` / `Integer`) instead.

Comment: Actually it is me who tried to anonymize the code, seachDocument sdocument is the same parameter :) 

I dont think its an syntactical error as the code has worked for a few years on glassfish